# private image included in a Class

Tags: c#, winforms, class

Alright so I'm doing a program that will hopefully select a game at random and display the information based on that class. So right now I have

```
namespace Twitch_Roulette
{
    class GameClass
    {
        private string gameName;
        private string developer;
        private string publisher;
        private string releaseDate;
        private string platform;
        private string genre;
        private string numPlayers;
        private string description;
    }
}
```

and next I want to include an image that is going to be the game's boxart, but how would I do that?

Comment: What's your project type? wpf, winForm...

Comment: How do I include an image in the class that will correspond with gameName. Also thank you for the edit. winForm is the project type.

Comment: Just a thought, but `releaseDate` Should that not be a `DateTime` and `genre` should be a `enum` and `numPlayers` a `int`?

Comment: Correct, it was just easier to put everything as strings to have their outputs in the form without converting it to strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
namespace Twitch_Roulette
{
    class GameClass
    {
        private string gameName;
        private string developer;
        private string publisher;
        private string releaseDate;
        private string platform;
        private string genre;
        private string numPlayers;
        private string description;
        private Image boxArt;
    }
}
```

The Image class resides in System.Drawing which you probably must include with a using statement at the top of the file.

```
using System.Drawing;
```

Comment: Alright and when I'm putting it in public GameClass() I'd do boxArt = ??

Comment: Image is an abstract class which means you need a derived class like [Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) to instanciate a new object. boxArt = new Bitmap("drive://folder//file.jpg"); should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the class like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GameClass gameclass = new GameClass();
        gameclass.GameName = "Name of Game";
        gameclass.GameGenre = GameClass.Genre.RPG;
        //Add the rest of the fields here.
    }
}
```

The GameClass Class looks like this:

```
class GameClass
{
    public enum Genre
    {
        RPG,
        MMO,
        RTS,
        Other
    }

    public enum Platform
    {
        Windows,
        Linux,
        MAC
    }

    private string gameName;
    private string developer;
    private string publisher;
    private DateTime releaseDate;
    private Platform platform;
    private Genre genre;
    private int numPlayers;
    private string description;
    private Bitmap picture;

    public string GameName
    {
        get
        {
            return gameName;
        }
        set
        {
            gameName = value;
        }
    }

    public Genre GameGenre
    {
        get
        {
            return genre;
        }
        set
        {
            genre = value;
        }
    }

    //... Other get set methods
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As easy as this (`System.Drawing.dll` must be included in your References):

```
class GameClass
{
    //your fields

    private System.Drawing.Bitmap image;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Hossein, just wanted to make sure. Didn't learn anything about Drawing in my course :/